# Java Class Extension ( Over riding)

Tags: java

I am trying to extend a binary number class but when i do i cant access some of the base class functions for example the last function i trying to run in main

```
import java.util.*;

class BinaryNumber
{
    private boolean b[];

    public void setBit(int index, boolean value)
    {
        b[index] = value;
    }

    public boolean getBit(int index)
    {
        return b[index];
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            b[i] = false;
    }

    public BinaryNumber()
    {
        b = new boolean[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            b[i] = false;
        }
    }

    public void inputNumber(int a)
    {

        if (a > 11111111)
        {
            System.out.println(" Exception Number to Large Nothing Entered ");
        }
        else
        {

            int number = a;
            int c = 7;
            int digit = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                digit = number % 10;
                if (digit == 1)
                {
                    b[c] = true;
                }
                else if (digit == 0)
                {
                    b[c] = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(" Only Binary Number Accepted ");
                    clear();
                    i = 8; // break
                }
                number = number / 10;
                c--;
            }
        }
    }

    public void outputNumber()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if (b[i] == true)
            {
                System.out.print("1");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("0");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public BinaryNumber ANDNumbers(BinaryNumber second)
    {
        BinaryNumber result = new BinaryNumber();
        boolean temp = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            result.setBit(i, (b[i] && second.b[i]));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

class ExtendedBinaryNumber

```
class ExtendedBinaryNumber extends BinaryNumber
{
    public ExtendedBinaryNumber binaryAdd(ExtendedBinaryNumber A)
    {
        ExtendedBinaryNumber result = new ExtendedBinaryNumber();
        boolean carry = false;

        for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (getBit(i) == true)
            {
                if (A.getBit(i) == false)
                {
                    if (carry == false)
                    {
                        carry = false;
                        result.setBit(i, true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        carry = true;
                        result.setBit(i, false);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (carry == false)
                    {
                        carry = true;
                        result.setBit(i, false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        carry = true;
                        result.setBit(i, true);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (A.getBit(i) == false)
                {
                    if (carry == false)
                    {
                        carry = false;
                        result.setBit(i, false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        carry = true;
                        result.setBit(i, true);
                        carry = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (carry == false)
                    {
                        carry = false;
                        result.setBit(i, true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        carry = true;
                        result.setBit(i, false);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

class Q6

```
class Q6
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        ExtendedBinaryNumber numA = new ExtendedBinaryNumber();
        int a = Integer.parseInt("10010111");
        numA.inputNumber(a);
        numA.outputNumber();

        ExtendedBinaryNumber numB = new ExtendedBinaryNumber();
        int b = Integer.parseInt("10010101");
        numB.inputNumber(b);
        numB.outputNumber();

        System.out.println("");

        // BinaryNumber c=numA.ANDNumbers(numB);
        // c.outputNumber();

        // ExtendedBinaryNumber dd=numA.binaryAdd(numB);
        // dd.outputNumber();

        ExtendedBinaryNumber dde = numA.ANDNumbers(numB);
        dde.outputNumber();

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"cant access some of the base class functions "_? Do you get an exception? A compiler error? Please update your post and tell us what error/exception you are getting.

Comment: If I understand your question: the "last function i trying to run in main" is "ANDNumbers()".  But you are having it put its return value into an ExtendedBinaryNumber, and the method returns a BinaryNumber.

Comment: I get that point . but what i make the return type to extentedbinary . then if i make an object of simplebinary it again wont work

Comment: what's the exception you get?

Answer (score 0):

`numA.ANDNumbers` returns a `BinaryNumber` and you're assign it to a `ExtendedBinaryNumber` variable. By default, you should do a downcasting to allow this, but be careful that you're really returning a `ExtendedBinaryNumber` instance when executing that line, or else you will have a `ClassCastException`.

The best way to solve this would be:

```
BinaryNumber dde=numA.ANDNumbers(numB);
dde.outputNumber();
```

---

If you really want to use the overriding powers in Java, you can override the `ANDNumbers` method in your `ExtendedBinaryNumber` class and return a covariant type, which in this case would be the `ExtendedBinaryNumber`:

```
class ExtendedBinaryNumber {
    public ExtendedBinaryNumber binaryAdd(ExtendedBinaryNumber A) {
        //here goes your actual code...
    }

    @Override
    public ExtendedBinaryNumber ANDNumbers(BinaryNumber second) {
        //fancy override implemententation that returns ExtendedBinaryNumber instance
    }
}
```

By doing this, now your line could compile and run happily ever after

```
ExtendedBinaryNumber dde = numA.ANDNumbers(numB);
dde.outputNumber();
```

Answer (score 0):

`ANDNumbers` method returns `BinaryNumber`, so there are incompatible types in the line `ExtendedBinaryNumber dde=numA.ANDNumbers(numB);`

Answer (score 0):

There is no override issue. You are fine except the return type of the method.

change

```
    ExtendedBinaryNumber dde = numA.ANDNumbers(numB);
```

to

```
    BinaryNumber dde = numA.ANDNumbers(numB);
```

as `ANDNumbers` method returns `BinaryNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

in class ExtendedBinaryNumber

```
@override
public void outputNumber() {
  super.outputNumber();
}

@override
public BinaryNumber ANDNumbers(BinaryNumber second) {
  return super.BinaryNumber();
}
```

in class Q6

```
BinaryNumber c=numA.ANDNumbers(numB);
    // c.outputNumber();

ExtendedBinaryNumber dd=numA.binaryAdd(numB);
dd.outputNumber();
```